# Play audio stream with javascript API

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have a web-server that streams wav audio and I would like to play it in a web browser using the javascript audio API.

Here is my code :

```
function start() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer"; // Read as binary data

    request.onload = function() {
        var data = request.response;
        playSound(data);
    };
}
```

The problem here is that onload wont be called until the data is completely loaded which is not very convenient for streaming.

So I looked for another event and found onProgress but the problem is that request.response returns null if the data is not completely loaded.

Whats the correct way to play an audio stream with javascript ?

Thank's for your help.

Lukas

Comment: Why dou you need ajax for such an issue. Just change the `src` of the `audio`.

Comment: The problem is that I want to do live streaming and the delay was too big with the audio element. That's why I tried with ajax.